# Will this MySQL quearly select all of the authors who wrote a book?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am haveing a lot of trouble trying to work out this question

> Write a query to show the number of authors who have written a book
>
> Author(AuthorID, AuthorName, Address, TelephoneNo, PublisherCode)
>
> Book (BookID, Name, ReleaseDate, Price, AuthorID)

I have

```
SELECT a.AuthorName, COUNT(b.*) AS ‘number of books written’
FROM Author a JOIN Book b ON  a.AuthorID = b.BookID 
GROUP BY a.AuthorName;
```

Which counts the number of books each author has written.

This is not the correct I know, but I can not figure it out??

Comment: The simplest query that will satisfy the specification would be `COUNT(DISTINCT b.authorid) FROM book b`.

Comment: @ spencer7593: would it look something like this? `SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT  AuthorID) AS ‘Number of authors who have wrote a book’
FROM Author a;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the requirement is to count authors that have at least one book, the simplest query to satisfy that would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.authorid)
  FROM book b
```

We probably want to assign an alias (name) to the returned column:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.authorid) AS `count_of_authors_who_have_at_least_one_book`
  FROM book b
```

We could also do a join to the `author` table, but that isn't necessary here, unless there are values of `authorid` in the `book` table that don't appear in the `author` table (i.e. there's not a foreign key constraint, or referential integrity is not enforced)

Queries to get authors that have two or more books would be a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM ( -- authors of two or more books 
         SELECT b.authorid
           FROM book b
          GROUP
             BY b.authorid
         HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2  
       ) c
```

If we want authors that have EXACTLY one book (not two or more) we can tweak the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count_authors_of_exactly_one_book`
  FROM ( -- authors of exactly one book
         SELECT b.authorid
           FROM book b
          GROUP
             BY b.authorid
         HAVING COUNT(1) = 1  
       ) c
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. You need to join on the author ID. You are currently mixing the author and book ID's, which won't match correctly.

```sql
SELECT 
   a.AuthorName, 
   COUNT(b.*) AS ‘number of books written’
FROM Author a 
JOIN Book b ON a.AuthorID = b.AuthorID 
GROUP BY a.AuthorName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get just a number that indicate total count of Author that wrote at least on book use below query

```
select count(*) as author_count from Author where exists (select 1 from Book where Book.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID)
```